# Assigning content of a pandas DataFrame cell based on some condition without using loops

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas DataFrame df with the following content:

```
Serial N       voltage       current
   B              10            nan
   B              10            nan
   C              12            nan
   D              40            nan
   .               .             .
   AB             12            nan
```

I also have the following dictionary which contains the current values as following (my key here is the serial number):

```
my_dict={A:0.6,B:0.2, ...,AB:0.2}
```

I would like to store the content of my dictionary into the dataFrame column "current" based on the dictionary. I can have multiple serial number in the dataFrame df with the same value. I would like to do so without using loops if possible. I tried this:

```
for k,v in my_dict.items():
   if df["Serial N"]==k:           
       df["current"]=v
```

But it does not  to work, Because I do not have the position of the rows (I can have several Serial number with same value; example: B in the Serial N column) where the condition is satisfied.  How can I do this without a loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html):

```
print df
  Serial N  voltage  current
0        B       10      NaN
1        B       10      NaN
2        C       12      NaN
3        D       40      NaN
4       AB       12      NaN

my_dict={"A":0.6,"B":0.2,"AB":0.2}
print my_dict
{'A': 0.6, 'B': 0.2, 'AB': 0.2}

df['current'] =  df['Serial N'].map(my_dict)
print df
  Serial N  voltage  current
0        B       10      0.2
1        B       10      0.2
2        C       12      NaN
3        D       40      NaN
4       AB       12      0.2
```

Comment: I have a concern tough, if I have a second dictionary which I would like to match, the values of the initial dataFrame are still nan even tough they have different Serial N

Comment: Can you add some example about second dictionary? If you need answer quickly, you can create new question? If not quickly, you can modify this question and I will try to find solution tomorrow, because now I am busy. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you. I found a quick solution by looping through the dictionary of dictionaries and making a single dictionary out of this. I then applied your solution. Thanks again.